# jupyterlab: matplotlib outputs not synchronized within loop

Tags: matplotlib, jupyter-lab

I need your help to understand why the following (simplified) minimal example does not give me the expected output (each graph after each display line.)

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import random
for i in range(2):
    print("i =", i)
    no_of_balls = 25
    x = [random.triangular() for i in range(no_of_balls)]
    y = [random.gauss(0.5, 0.25) for i in range(no_of_balls)]
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(6,4))
    fig.gca().plot(x, y)
```

nota: I cannot use `fig.show()` in my case because I use axe propertie of figure and otherwise  I get the following message

> .../site-packages/matplotlib/figure.py:457: UserWarning: matplotlib is currently using a non-GUI backend, so cannot show the figure
> "matplotlib is currently using a non-GUI backend, "

Thanks in advance for your kind help.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the use of `display` fixes the code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import random
for i in range(2):
    display("i =" + str(i))  # <--- changed here
    no_of_balls = 25
    x = [random.triangular() for i in range(no_of_balls)]
    y = [random.gauss(0.5, 0.25) for i in range(no_of_balls)]
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(6,4))
    fig.gca().plot(x, y)
    display(fig)   # <--- changed here (new line)
```